# Find sum of stacked/overlapping date intersections in SQL table

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have the following table which represents bookings of articles:

```
+---+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
|id | article_id | quantity |  starts_at  |   ends_at   |
+---+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
| 1 |          1 |        1 | 2015-03-01  | 2015-03-20  |
| 2 |          1 |        2 | 2015-03-02  | 2015-03-03  |
| 3 |          1 |        3 | 2015-03-04  | 2015-03-15  |
| 4 |          1 |        2 | 2015-03-16  | 2015-03-22  |
| 5 |          1 |        2 | 2015-03-11  | 2015-03-19  |
| 6 |          2 |        2 | 2015-03-06  | 2015-03-22  |
| 7 |          2 |        3 | 2015-03-02  | 2015-03-04  |
+---+------------+----------+-------------+-------------+
```

From this table I want to extract the following information:

```
+------------+----------+
| article_id | sum      |  
+------------+----------+
|          1 |        6 | 
|          2 |        3 | 
+------------+----------+
```

Sum represents the max sum of quantity of stacked/overlapping booked articles for the given time ranges. In the first table article with id=1 has its maximum from booking 1, 3 and 5.

Is there any MySQL solution to obtain this information from a table like this?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: The date intersections are crucial. Let's say booking 5 starts at 2015-03-17 the sum for article_id=1 results 5, because booking 3 and 5 are not overlapping anymore. The sql should automatically consider all possible overlapping possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is going to seem crazy complicated, perhaps; but it isn't, if one accepts that the use of a calendar table is an excellent MySQL idiom for dealing with date range related issues.  I've closely adapted calendar table code from [Artful Software's calendar table](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=95) article. [Artful Software's query techniques](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php) are a wonderful resource for doing complicated things in MySQL. The calendar table gives you a row per individual date that you are working with, which makes many things much easier.

For the whole thing below, [you can go to this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9442a/1) for a place to play around with the code. It'll take a while to load.

First, here is your data:

```
CREATE TABLE articles
(`id` int, `article_id` int, `quantity` int, `starts_at` datetime, `ends_at` datetime);


INSERT INTO articles
    (`id`, `article_id`, `quantity`, `starts_at`, `ends_at`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1, '2015-03-01 00:00:00', '2015-03-20 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1, 2, '2015-03-02 00:00:00', '2015-03-03 00:00:00'),
    (3, 1, 3, '2015-03-04 00:00:00', '2015-03-15 00:00:00'),
    (4, 1, 2, '2015-03-16 00:00:00', '2015-03-22 00:00:00'),
    (5, 1, 2, '2015-03-11 00:00:00', '2015-03-19 00:00:00'),
    (6, 2, 2, '2015-03-06 00:00:00', '2015-03-22 00:00:00'),
    (7, 2, 3, '2015-03-02 00:00:00', '2015-03-04 00:00:00');
```

Next, here is the creation of the calendar table--I've created somewhat more date rows than needed (going back to start of year, and forward to start of next year).  Ideally you just permanently keep a more massive calendar table on hand, covering a span of dates that will handle anything you could ever need.  **All the stuff below is going to seem quite lengthy and complex.  But if you already have a calendar table lying around, the whole next section is not necessary.**

```
CREATE TABLE calendar ( dt datetime primary key ); 

/* the views below will be joined and rejoined to themselves to
   get the effect creating many rows.  V ends up with 10 rows. */
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v3 as SELECT 1 n UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1; 
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v as SELECT 1 n FROM v3 a, v3 b UNION ALL SELECT 1;

/* Going to limit the calendar table to first of year of min date
   and first of year after max date */
SELECT @min := makedate(year(min(starts_at)),1) FROM articles;
SELECT @max := makedate(year(min(ends_at))+1,1)  FROM articles;
SET @inc = -1;

/* below we work with @min date + @inc days successively, with @inc:=@inc+1
   acting like ++variable, so we start with minus 1.
   We insert as many individual date rows as we want by self-joining v,
   and using some kind of limit via WHERE to keep the calendar table small
   for our example. For n occurrences of v below, you get a max
   of 10^n rows in the calendar table. We are using v as row-creation
   engine. */
INSERT INTO calendar 
SELECT @min + interval @inc:=@inc+1 day as dt 
FROM v a, v b, v c, v d # , v e , v f
WHERE @inc < datediff(@max,@min);
```

Now we are ready to find the stackings.  Assuming the above (big assumption, I know), this becomes pretty easy.  I'm going to do it through a few views for readability.

```
/* now create a view that will let us easily view the articles
   related to indvidual dates when we query.
   Not necessary, just makes things easier to read. */
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW articles_to_dates as
SELECT c.dt, article_id
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN calendar c on c.dt between (SELECT min(starts_at) FROM articles) and (SELECT max(ends_at) FROM articles)
GROUP BY article_id, c.dt;

--SELECT * FROM articles_to_dates  --This query would show the view's result

/* next view is the total amount of articles booked per individual date */
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW booked_quantities_per_day AS
SELECT a2d.dt,a2d.article_id, SUM(a.quantity) as booked_quantity
FROM  articles_to_dates a2d
INNER JOIN articles a on a2d.dt between a.starts_at and a.ends_at and a.article_id = a2d.article_id
GROUP BY a2d.dt, a2d.article_id 
ORDER by a2d.article_id, a2d.dt

--SELECT * from booked_quantities_per_day --this query would show the view's result
```

Finally, here are the desired results:

```
SELECT article_id, max(booked_quantity) max_stacked 
FROM booked_quantities_per_day
GROUP BY article_id;
```

Results:

```
article_id  max_stacked
1   6
2   3
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your great response. Today I implemented it but for performance reasons without using views and it worked all most out of the box. Great work!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.
Two groups. First to get distinct list of possible 'quantity'; second - summarise them

```
SELECT article_id, SUM(sub.quantity) FROM
(SELECT article_id, quantity FROM table GROUP BY article_id, quantity) as sub
GROUP BY article_id
```

Comment: checking which bookings intersect when is crucial for the sum!

Answer (score -1):

```
select sum(quantity) from ... 
group by article_id 
where  
... select your date range ...
```